# Android In-App purchase refund

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app

I'm using the In-App purchase in my Application.

I created a test account and my build was in Alpha which could be able to download for tester.

When i prompt to buy a product it ask for Payment option. As by the docs, It says they will not charge for testing.

I came through docs that there is an option for refund. So for refund is there anything to control in the Code or it all will be controlled through the developer console . I'm using in-app version 3.

Please help me out here.. thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to control exactly?

Comment: Refunding in In app purchase.

Answer (score 2):

Refunds are given to users through your google merchant account.  [Here](https://wallet.google.com/merchant/) is a link to where you would go to do it.  The links in the developer console would just redirect you to your merchant account.